# Getting "parent resource not found" during ARM template deployment

Tags: azure-resource-manager

I have private DNS zone `zone.private` which is already deployed in resource group and I'm trying to add A record to it with ARM template below which fails with `Status Message: Can not perform requested operation on nested resource. Parent resource 'zone.private' not found. (Code:ParentResourceNotFound)`
I'm supposed to be able to refer to refer to resources deployed in the same resource group to deploy nested resources but it fails for whatever reason. I have another zone called `zone.domain.com` deployed to the same resource group and deploying to that succeeds with no issues.

```
      {
         "type": "Microsoft.Network/dnsZones/A",
         "apiVersion": "2018-05-01",
         "name": "[concat('zone.private', '/', 'webexport-lb')]",
         "properties": {
            "TTL": 3600,
            "ARecords": [
               {
                  "ipv4Address": "1.1.1.1"
               }
            ]
         }
      },
```

Comment: COuld you please check if you have created zone `zone.private` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a private DNS zone, you could use [Microsoft.Network/privateDnsZones/A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.network/privatednszones/a?tabs=json) instead of `Microsoft.Network/dnsZones/A`.

So change it like this:

```
  {
     "type": "Microsoft.Network/privateDnsZones/A",
     "apiVersion": "2018-09-01",
     "name": "[concat('zone.private', '/', 'webexport-lb')]",
     "properties": {
        "ttl": 3600,
        "aRecords": [
           {
              "ipv4Address": "1.1.1.1"
           }
        ]
     }
  }
```

Comment: This almost works. It's pretty crazy how even parameters casing is different between this resource and the one in public DNS zone. `TTL` vs `ttl`, `ARecords` vs `aRecords`. Please change answer with those changes so somebody else will not run into it